# Linq to SQL - Return top n rows

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

I want to return the TOP 100 records using Linq.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Use the Take extension method.

```
var query = db.Models.Take(100);
```

Answer (score 58):

You want to use Take(N);

```
var data = (from p in people
           select p).Take(100);
```

If you want to skip some records as well you can use Skip, it will skip the first N number:

```
var data = (from p in people
           select p).Skip(100);
```

Answer (score 14):

Example with order by:

```
var data = (from p in db.people  
            orderby p.IdentityKey descending 
            select p).Take(100);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Take()` extension

Example:

```
var query = (from foo in bar).Take(100)
```